# Building correct composite index for several columns MySql

Tags: mysql, indexing

I want to build composite index that will optimise the following query

```
SELECT DISTINCT company_id FROM datavalues 
WHERE prefix = 'SON'
AND date_updated < '2020-07-15 23:59:59'
AND end_date > '2020-07-15';
```

Is this the most optimal index? Im confused how indexes work with `DISTINCT`

```
CREATE INDEX index_name
ON datavalues (company_id ,prefix ,date_updated, end_date );
```

Please help. I am new to Mysql indexes.

Comment: You create covering index... but the 1st column must be `prefix` and the 2nd - either `date_updated` or `end_date`. Put `company_id` last. *how indexes work with DISTINCT* Not used.

Comment: From the info provided in the question there's no reason to suppose an index will make any difference at all. You could test and compare before and after adding index an run an explain to see if your index is used.

Comment: Also "index hints" can be used rather than adding/dropping indexes -- a faster way to test an index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Start each column tested with `=`, in any order:  `INDEX(prefix, ...)`.
2. Then move on to one range:  `INDEX(prefix, date_updated, ...)` or `INDEX(prefix, end_date, ...)`.  Include both; let the Optimizer discover which will be better.
3. Finally, consider making the index "covering", as you did.

So, I recommend providing two composite, covering, indexes:

```
INDEX(prefix, date_updated, end_date, company_id)
INDEX(prefix, end_date, date_updated, company_id)
```

(Putting `company_id` first is not good -- it won't help with the `WHERE`, and barely helps with the "covering".)

More cases and discussion:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql

`DISTINCT` is a dedupping pass between `WHERE` and `ORDER BY`.  (Also, `DISTINCT` is mostly redundant with `GROUP BY`.)  `DISTINCT` and `INDEX` do interact, but not in your example.

*Caveat:*  If you change *anything* in that query, my advice may be nullified.

Comment: If DISTINCT and INDEX do not interact in my example, why need I `company_id ` in the index?

Comment: I added to make the `INDEX` "covering" -- and a slight performance improvement because the query can be performed entirely in the INDEX's BTree.